# C++ how to sort using non comparison based method

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

-You do a pass through the student array to count how many students there are in each school. You store the counts in a counts array.

-You allocate another array of Students with size equal to the input array. You will use this temp array to hold the sorted elements.

-Using the counts array you calculate the beginning index for each school in the sorted array by noticing that the starting index for a school is the cumulative number of students for all
the schools before it in the array. E.g.: if the counts are 5, 10, 12 for schools a, b, c then the
starting indexes for each school's students in the sorted array are 0, 5, 15

– You do another pass through the student array and whenever you encounter a student from a
school you add that student to the right portion of the helper array and increment that
portion's index.

-The helper array is now sorted by school and by ID within each school. Copy the helper
array's elements to the input array.

*I'm having trouble with the last two bullet points. On paper i understand what the algorithm is doing but implementing the code is difficult for me.*

The code I have below uses a counter to keep track of how many students go into 7 different school represented by the index of the counter array. It then does a cumulative count. What i need to code now starts from the right of my temp array and uses the cumulative to sort the array.

```
 void sortByGroupById2(Student students[], int len) {
    int temp[len];
    int count[7];

        // Creates an array where schools are converted to ints by using schoolToIndex
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            temp[i] =schoolToIndex(students[i].getSchool());
            cout << i << " " << temp[i] << endl;
        }


        // Sets every index in count array to 0
        for(int i =0; i < 7;  i++) {
            count[i]=0;
        }

        //Counts the number of student in 7 different schools
        for(int j =0; j < len;  j++) {
          count[temp[j]]++;
        }
        cout << "====" << endl;

        for(int i =0; i < 7;  i++) {
            cout<< i << " "  <<count[i] <<endl;
        }

          cout << "====" << endl;


        // cumulative counts so we get the starting index for each group
        int total = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
            int tmp = count[i];
            count[i] = tmp +total;
            total += tmp;
          cout << i << " " << count[i] << endl;
        }

        // Sorts into a new array

        for(int i=0; i <7;i++){

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you just asking for the [counting sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm)?

Comment: could you explain the third loop of the algorithm? That's what I'm having trouble picturing.

Comment: Note that the last bullet points says, "The helper array is now sorted by school and by ID within each school". In the helper array, the student IDs within each school's partition will be sorted only if the original input is sorted by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the steps exactly as written:

```
// -You allocate another array of Students with size equal to the input array. 
Student* sorted_students = new Student[len];

// – You do another pass through the student array ....
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) 
{
    // and whenever you encounter a student from a school ...
    int key = schoolToIndex(students[i].getSchool());

    // you add that student to the right portion of the helper array ...
    sorted_students[count[key]] = students[i];

    //  and increment that portion's index.
    count[key] += 1;
}

// -The helper array is now sorted by school and by ID within each school. 
// Copy the helper array's elements to the input array.
std::copy(sorted_students, sorted_students + len, students);

// and don't forget to delete!
delete [] sorted_students;
```